# Chaine rule and partial derivative !!

Tags: real-analysis

i have this simple question :

in a course of differential equations i found this sentence :

let $u:\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by $u(x,t)=g(x-t\overrightarrow{b})$ where $x$ and $\overrightarrow{b} \in\mathbb{R}^n$ $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $g$ is a given function .

my question is :

why will we have this (or how to use chaine rules to find this result) :

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\sum_1^n -b_i\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}(x-t\overrightarrow{b})$

(every functions are differentiables)

thank you very much !

Comment: The equation you wrote down is just the transport equation in $n$ dimensions, so I'm guessing you left some things out of your question.. You'll need to be more specific and add any such additional information to your original post.

Comment: Hint: Chain rule

Comment: @ Mattos thanks for unswering , it s exactly the the transport equation in n dimensions , but i didn't want to be more specific because it s only this result that i didn t understand .... can you show me just how to use chain rule here (in the 2 dimension for example  ) !!

Answer (score 0):

let me take $n= 2.$ the general case should be similar. we have 
$$u(x_1, x_2, t) = g(x_1-tb_1, x_2-tb_2)\tag 1.$$  hold $x_1, x_2$ fixed and differentiate with respect to $t.$  we have 
$$\begin{align}u_t(x_1, x_2, t) &= g_{x_1}( x_1-tb_1, x_2-tb_2)\frac{d}{dt}(x_1-tb_1)+g_{x_2}( x_1-tb_1, x_2-tb_2)\frac{d}{dt}(x_2-tb_2)\\
&=-b_1g_{x_1}( x_1-tb_1, x_2-tb_2)-b_2g_{x_2}( x_1-tb_1, x_2-tb_2)\end{align}$$

Comment: @ abel , thanks for unswering , i understood well what you  wrote, but is this the chaine rule in (many variables case ) ?? or it s an other rule ??

Comment: we are using the chain rule when we compute $\frac{d}{dt}\left(g(x_1-tb_1, x_2-tb_2)\right)$ and get two terms for the answer.