# Partial derivatives and using the chain rule

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have this simple question:

In a course of differential equations I found this sentence:

Let $u:\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by $u(x,t)=g(x-t\overrightarrow{b})$ where $x,\overrightarrow{b} \in\mathbb{R}^n$, $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $g$ is a given function.

My question is:

Why will we have this (or how to use chaine rules to find this result) :

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\sum_{i=1}^n -b_i\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}(x-t\overrightarrow{b}),$$

(all partial derivatives exist).

Thank you very much!

Comment: i answered here. is this not the same as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616976/chaine-rule-and-partial-derivative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $u(\vec x,t)=\left . g(\vec y)\right|_{\vec y=\vec x- \vec b t}$, then from the chain rule we can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u(\vec x,t)}{\partial t}&=\frac{\partial g(\vec x - \vec b t)}{\partial t}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \left. \left(\frac{\partial g(\vec y)}{\partial y_i}\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial t}\right)\right|_{y_i=x_i-b_it}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \left. \left(-b_i\frac{\partial g(\vec y)}{\partial y_i}\right)\right|_{y_i=x_i-b_it}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \left(-b_i\frac{\partial g(\vec x-\vec b t)}{\partial x_i}\right)
\end{align}$$

since $\frac{\partial  y_i}{\partial x_i}=1$.

Comment: @ A.P. @ Dr. MV thank you very much , i understood your unswers, i have only a last question : just when we have here  $u(x,t)=g(x-t\overrightarrow{b})$ then the ambiguity for me is that $u$ is a function of $n+1$ variables but $g$ has only $n$ variables

Comment: , then will we have $\nabla g(x-tb)=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1}(x-tb), \ldots, \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n}(x-tb)\end{pmatrix} $=$\nabla u=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}, \ldots, \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_n},\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\end{pmatrix}.$ ??

Comment: is that true , this result ?

Comment: Actually, $g(\vec x-\vec b t)$ is a function of $n+1$ variables, since $\vec x$ is comprised of $n$ components.

Comment: @ Dr. MV  i didn t understand........ we have  $g(\vec x-\vec b t)=g(x_1-tb_1,...,x_n-tb_n)$ there are only $n$ variables, isn't it ?

Comment: or may be $t$ is just a parameter  !!!!!

Comment: We consider $t$ as a variable since we are differentiating with respect to $t$.

Comment: @ Dr. MV , i know that my question is stupid , but do you think so that $\nabla g(x-tb)=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1}(x-tb), \ldots, \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n}(x-tb)\end{pmatrix} =\nabla u=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}, \ldots, \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_n},\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\end{pmatrix}$ a vector of $n$ variables is equal to a vector of $n+1$ variables ?

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $u(x,\cdot)$ is the composite function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $t \mapsto x - tb$ followed by $x \mapsto g(x)$. The derivative of the first map $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is given by $$\begin{pmatrix} - b_1 \\ \vdots \\ - b_n\end{pmatrix}$$ and the derivative of the second map $g:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is given by $$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1}, \ldots, \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n}\end{pmatrix}.$$

Thus the derivative of the composite map at some $t$ is $$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1}(x-tb), \ldots, \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n}(x-tb)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} - b_1 \\ \vdots \\ - b_n\end{pmatrix} = \sum_{i=1}^n -b_i\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}(x-tb).$$